# Modified Sine Equation

Tags: mechanical-engineering

[image: Modified Sine]

I'm trying to create an excel sheet that will use the modified sine equation above to output a 360° displacement chart when a user types in the acceleration, velocity, total distance traveled and start and stop angles. From what I've been told previously this is the equation I have to use, but my background is more on the excel side of things so I'm having trouble understanding exactly how to break this equation down into something I can use.

Could someone please explain how to solve this equation using the variables that will be available that I described above? Does this equation require any more or any less variables than what will be available?

Comment: Just inspecting your equations, you have a parametric form of a plot. You can run these equations over any range of theta from 0 to Beta. You must include the parameter h or y in order to get a solution.  Just shooting from the hip here but if you set Beta = 360 deg and use 3 nested if statements in excel I don't see any problem with plotting Theta vs. y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the `h` and `beta` constants, either in a cell or as a [defined name](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/11/excel-name-named-range-define-use/). 
After that, you can create a column with the `theta` parameter and another column with the calculated `y` parameter.

The formula for the `y` should use the [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) and [AND](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) functions. Suppose the `theta` parameters are on column A. The formula should be something like

```
=IF(AND(0<=A1,A1<beta/8),h*(PI()/(4+PI()))*A1/beta - 1/4/(4+PI())*SIN(4*PI()*A1/beta),IF(AND(beta/8<=A1,A1<7*beta/8),h*(2*/(4+PI()))+PI()/(4+PI()))*A1/beta - 9/4/(4+PI())*SIN(4*PI()*A1/3/beta),h*(4/(4+PI()))+PI()/(4+PI()))*A1/beta - 1/4/(4+PI())*SIN(4*PI()*A1/beta) ) )
```

To break down the formula, the IFs statements define which equation to use. 
The criteria is accessed with the AND function, since you have a range on beta. The equation itself is straightforward.